# 500 Internal Server Error on POST in MERN Application Running on Localhost

Tags: node.js, reactjs, post, http-status-code-500

I a getting a 500 Internal Server Error when I am sending a POST request from frontend to backend. Any idea on how can I fix it? I'm sharing the required code below for both frontend and backend. My backend is running on **port 5035** and frontend is running on **port 3000**. The exact error is:

```
POST http://localhost:5035/api/todos 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

**Frontend code where I'm sending the POST Request**

```
// Handles displaying components related to todo task list
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import TodoForm from "./TodoForm";
import TodoUpdate from "./TodoUpdate";
import axios from "axios";
function TodoTask() {
    //for the list of tasks
    const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
    //add task in the list of tasks
    const addTodo = async todo => {
        //check for empty input 
        if (!todo.text || /^\s*$/.test(todo.text)) {
            return
        }
        const newTodos = [todo, ...todos];
        setTodos(newTodos);
        console.log(todos);
        try {
            await axios.post("http://localhost:5035/api/todos", {
             todo
            });
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
          }

    }
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

    return (
        <div id="container">
            <h1 className="display-1">My To Do List Application</h1>
            <p className="lead">This is a basic to do list application with complete frontend and backend configuration. For details, check ReadMe.md of this project.</p>
            {/* calling the form component to show a text field */}
            <label htmlFor="formGroupExampleInput">Enter your to do here:</label>
            <TodoForm onSubmit={addTodo} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default TodoTask;
```

**Backend Code in MVC Architecture**

**index.js**

```
// import dependencies
const express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const router = require('./routers/routes');
const cors = require('cors');

// set up dependencies
var app = express();
app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use('/api/', router);

// set up mongoose
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://sidrah:sidrah@cluster0.yidsza6.mongodb.net/dbtodolist?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
  .then(()=> {
    console.log('Database connected');
  })
  .catch((error)=> {
    console.log('Error connecting to database');
  });
// set up port
const port = 5035;
// set up route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({
    message: 'Welcome to todo list',
  });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Our server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

**Model.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const MyTodoListSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
todo: {
type: String,
default: "",
required: true
}
const MyTodoList = mongoose.model("MyTodoList", MyTodoListSchema, 'coltodolist');
module.exports = MyTodoList;
```

**Controller.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const MyTodoList = require('../models/model');

exports.createTodo = (req, res) => {
  const todo = new MyTodoList({
     todo: req.body.todo
  });
  return todo
    .save()
    .then((newTodo) => {
      return res.status(201).json({
        success: true,
        message: 'New todo list created successfully',
        MyTodoList: newTodo,
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.status(500).json({
        success: false,
        message: 'Server error. Please try again.',
        error: error.message,
      });
    });
}  

//get all todos
exports.getAllTodo = (req, res) => {
      res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
      res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
      res.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1800");
      res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "content-type");
      res.setHeader( "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, POST, GET, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS" ); 
  MyTodoList.find()
    .select('taskId todo priority')
 ); 
    .then((allTodo) => {
      return res.status(200).json({
        Todo: allTodo
      });
      
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).json({
        success: false,
        message: 'Server error. Please try again.',
        error: err.message,
      });
    });
  }
```

**Router.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const todolist_controller = require('../controllers/controller')
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
router.post('/todos', todolist_controller.createTodo);
router.get('/todos', todolist_controller.getAllTodo);
module.exports = router;
```

Can someone please suggest a solution? The POST is working fine with POSTMAN, but not working from frontend. Any thing I should be fixing?

Comment: In your Controller.js, can you console.log(req) to see what exactly is coming through?

Comment: I tried. I'm not getting anything on Console.log. Is it perhaps because the request is not passed to the server?

Comment: I just checked. I'm getting a warning in Console in frontend application. The warning is  "Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `exact`." Maybe it is causing the issue?

Comment: Nope, that warning wasn't the issue. I'm still getting 500 error.